# How can I create list of results in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I did write a cost calculator, the costs can be more than one value of same inputs so I need to find minimum cost. The calculator is running corrently, but I couldn't do put into a list and find the minumum value of the list, how can I do it?
This is my calculator,

```
cal(X,Y,CLIST) :- calcualtor(X,Y,C).
calcualtor(X,Y,C ) :- calculate_cost(X,Z,A), calcualtor(Z,Y,B),C is A+B.
calcualtor(X,Y,C) :-  calculate_cost(X,Y,C).
```

When I call `cal(A,B,X)` it gives `X = 7` then when I press ";" it gives `X
= 5` then when I press ";" it gives `X = 14`etc.

I want to `[7,5,14,..]` then find the min value of the list.

Note: I can't use swi library functions

Comment: `findall(X,cal(A,B,X),Xs)`

Comment: Oh, thanks but I can't use the function, its forbidden .

Comment: Then I guess you will have to use the database (`assert/1` and `retract/1`).

Comment: `I can't use swi-library functions` but you can implement them by yourself :D

Comment: Do a search on this site for `[prolog] without findall`. There are many questions and answers already on the topic of all kinds. I'm sure you'll find something that should help, if you're interested in working at it a little.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a list ? You're looking for the minimum. That is, look for a value that does **not** have another greater that it. The explicit negation - called [\+](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%5C%2B)/1) - is key to force Prolog to evaluate alternative bindings.